# MongoDB - Filtrando retornos

Tags: node.js, mongodb

gostaria de saber como eu posso estar filtrando os resultados retornados nas minhas consultas no mongodb neste meu cenário eu irei ter que retornar os nomes dos setores e os contatos referentes a cada setores a partir do ID da empresa, porém eu gostaria de retornar apenas os registros que estejam marcados como ativos. Segue um exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você esteja usando o mongoose, para fazer o nodejs se comunicar com o mongodb, para isto todas as consultas que você fizer no banco, o primeiro parâmetro que você passa é o *json query*, e o segundo é o *callback*. O que você pode fazer e passar um segundo json com os dados que deseja, assim como no exemplo a seguir:

```
db.collection.find(querry,{(funciona igual do mongoshell)})
```

então sua função ficará como neste neste exemplo:

```
//
Model.find({_id:/*id qualquer*/}, {ativos: true}, (req, res)=>{
   // sua regra aqui
})
```

Comment: Dica: Não faça uso de abreviações ou gírias nas respostas.

Comment: Vlw, apesar de que o que vale e o conteúdo, e não a forma de escrita!!